# Finding a formula in intuitionist logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics

I am looking for a formula which is true semantically but not syntactically in propositional intuitionist logic.

Does it exist? If yes what's that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you specify the language and inference rules?

Comment: In light of the answer by Mauro Allegranza, could you please clarify the question?

Comment: In intuitionistic logic,I can't use truth table as I used before in  classical logic(I want to show that with an example that truth table does not works),I want to show that I can find a counter example which is semantically true,but not syntactically;the rules are MP and Subs and the language is the usual languages includes connectives,tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

If with "true semantically" you are referring to [Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/), there is no such formula, because

> **Kripke's Soundness and Completeness Theorems** establish that a sentence of [the language ] $L$ is provable in intuitionistic predicate logic if and only if it is forced by every node of every Kripke structure [i.e. it is *valid*].

---

If, instead, with "semantically true" you mean true with the "classical semantic" (e.g truth tables for propositional logic), then $P∨¬P$ is the simplest example of a formula which is (classically) true but underivable in intuitionsitic logic, because, due to Kripke's Sondness and Completeness Theorem, is not valid according to Kripke's semantic.